# Xamarin.Forms Grid Column's width not filling entire cell

Tags: xamarin.forms, grid, columndefinition

I have a `Grid` with 4 `Column`s. Column 1, 2, 4 are absolute. And I want column 3 to fill the space.

The problem I am having is: for some rows in the `Grid`, the column 3 data does not fill up the entire space, and so its column 4 is out of alignment with respect to the other rows. See image below for clarity:

[image]

Here is my code (newbie, trying to get a handle on the visual part of **XAML**).

```
<ListView x:Name="lstData" HasUnevenRows="True" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid Padding="0, 5, 0, 5" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="45"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Label Text="{Binding TimesheetDate}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="Micro"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding UserInitials}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="Micro"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding TaskSummary}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" FontSize="Micro"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding TimesheetHours, StringFormat='{}{0:f2}'}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" FontSize="Micro"></Label>

                    <Label Text="{Binding TaskID}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="Micro"></Label>
                    <Label Text="" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="Micro" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
                    <Label Text="{Binding UserComments}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" FontSize="Micro"></Label>
                    <Label Text="" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="Micro" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"></Label>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Thanks in advance,
Kris

Comment: Try setting HorizontalOptions on the main grid in the ViewCell to FillAndExpand, The grid may not be taking up all available space.

Comment: Did you actually found an answer to your question? If the Answer given solved your problem you should consider accepting it. In this way you improve this website!

Answer (score 2):

you could change your `HorizontalOptions` of your `Grid`,

change

```
<Grid Padding="0, 5, 0, 5" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
```

to:

```
 <Grid Padding="0, 5, 0, 5" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
```